# Self-defined function doesn't output data to environment?

Tags: r, function, readxl

I'm trying to create a small function to help read data from an excel spreadsheet hosted online.

```
read2014 <- function(urlhere, filename){
      url <- urlhere
      destfile <- filename
      curl::curl_download(url, destfile)
      filename <- read_excel(destfile, skip = 14)
}
```

When I try and call the function with these argument values though, nothing happens.

```
read2014(urlhere = "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/04/Beds-Open-Overnight-Web_File-Q1-2014-15-Revised-Nov15-Final-21447.xlsx", filename = "X2014_Q1")
```

However, when I call the body without using a function, it inputs the spreadsheet into the environment as a data frame with no problem.

```
url <- "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/04/Beds-Open-Overnight-Web_File-Q1-2014-15-Revised-Nov15-Final-21447.xlsx"
destfile <- "X2014_Q1.xlsx"
curl::curl_download(url, destfile)
X2014_Q1 <- read_excel(destfile, skip = 14)
```

I've never written functions before so I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Use `return(filename)` at the very end of your function this will return the filename to your environment.

Comment: @burton030 I've tried that and it displays into the console but not the environment.

Comment: `test <- read2014(urlhere = "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/04/Beds-Open-Overnight-Web_File-Q1-2014-15-Revised-Nov15-Final-21447.xlsx", filename = "X2014_Q1")` this shows the data in the environment.

Comment: I forgot to assign the output - careless mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments you forgot to assign the output.

```
object <- read2014(urlhere = "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/04/Beds-Open-Overnight-Web_File-Q1-2014-15-Revised-Nov15-Final-21447.xlsx", filename = "X2014_Q1")
```